# ReactJS how to render component when changes value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

i have wishlist. When i adding items to my wishlist, i am adding items to my localStorage. And i need to show how many items i added to my wishlist.
i dont know how to render header (automatically) when changes value in (localStorage).

When i add items to wishlist it shows in span tag, everything good but in console i am getting: Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded.

Can someone help please?
Everything is on header component(page)
Header Page:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Container, Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { ThemeContext } from '../GlobalComponents/ThemeProvider';
import { BiSun, BiMoon, BiCart } from 'react-icons/bi';
import { VscAccount } from 'react-icons/vsc';
import { Link } from "@reach/router";
import { useCart } from "react-use-cart";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";


const Header = () => {
  const { theme, setThemeMode } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(theme);
  const { loginWithRedirect, logout, isAuthenticated, user, isLoading } = useAuth0();

  const [count, setCount] = useState((JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("liked"))));


  const cou = () => {
    let oldData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('liked') || "[]")
    if (oldData.length === count.length) {
      setCount((JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("liked"))))
    } else {
      setCount((JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("liked"))))
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let oldData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('liked') || "[]")
    if (oldData.length === count.length) {
      setCount((JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("liked"))))
    } else {
      setCount((JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("liked"))))
    }
  }, [count]);




  useEffect(() => {
    setThemeMode(darkMode);
    console.log(darkMode)
  }, [darkMode]);

  const {
    isEmpty,
    totalItems,
  } = useCart();

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="md"
        variant={darkMode ? 'dark' : 'light'}
        className={darkMode ? 'bg-light-black border-bottom' : 'bg-light border-bottom'}
        style={{ width: '100%', position: 'fixed', zIndex: 100 }}
      >
        <Container>
          <Link to="/">
            <Navbar.Brand className={darkMode ? 'text-dark-primary' : 'text-light-primary'}>
              <img src='https://i.ibb.co/7kZrn4H/33342.png' width={200} />

            </Navbar.Brand>
          </Link>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="ms-auto">
              <div className='load'><div class="lds-ellipsis"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div></div>

              <Nav.Link
                className={darkMode ? 'text-dark-primary' : 'text-light-primary'}
                onClick={() => setDarkMode(!darkMode)}
              >
                {darkMode ? <BiSun size="1.7rem" /> : <BiMoon size="1.7rem" />}
              </Nav.Link>
              <Link
                to="/cart"
                className={`${darkMode ? 'text-dark-primary' : 'text-light-primary'} d-flex align-items-center`}
              >
                <BiCart size="2rem" />
                {!isEmpty && <span style={{ position: 'relative', left: '-21px', top: '-18px' }}>{totalItems}</span>}
                <span style={{ marginLeft: !isEmpty ? '-13px' : 0 }}>&nbsp;Cart</span>
              </Link>
              <Link
                to="/wishlist"
                className={`${darkMode ? 'text-dark-primary' : 'text-light-primary'} d-flex align-items-center`}
              >
                <BiCart size="2rem" />
                {!isEmpty && <span style={{ position: 'relative', left: '-21px', top: '-18px' }}></span>}
                <span style={{ marginLeft: !isEmpty ? '-13px' : 0 }}>&nbsp;Wishlist</span>
              </Link>
              {
                isAuthenticated ? (
                  <>

                    <button onClick={() => logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: window.location.origin } })} className={`login-btn ${darkMode ? 'text-dark-primary' : 'text-light-primary'}`}>
                      Log Out
                    </button>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <>

                    <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()} className={`login-btn ${darkMode ? 'text-dark-primary' : 'text-light-primary'}`}>
                      Log in
                    </button>
                  </>
                )
              }
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    );
  };




  return (
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="md"
      variant={darkMode ? 'dark' : 'light'}
      className={darkMode ? 'bg-light-black border-bottom' : 'bg-light border-bottom'}
      style={{ width: '100%', position: 'fixed', zIndex: 100 }}
    >
      {/* <button onClick={()=>cou()}>Ref</button> */}
      <Container>
        <Link to="/">
          <Navbar.Brand className={darkMode ? 'text-dark-primary' : 'text-light-primary'}>
            <img src='https://i.ibb.co/7kZrn4H/33342.png' width={200} />

          </Navbar.Brand>
        </Link>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="ms-auto">
            {
              isAuthenticated && (
                <>
                  <p className={`d-flex align-items-center user-name ${darkMode ? 'text-dark-primary' : 'text-light-primary'}`}>{user.email}</p>
                </>

              )
            }
            <Nav.Link
              className={darkMode ? 'text-dark-primary' : 'text-light-primary'}
              onClick={() => setDarkMode(!darkMode)}
            >
              {darkMode ? <BiSun size="1.7rem" /> : <BiMoon size="1.7rem" />}
            </Nav.Link>
            <Link
              to="/cart"
              className={`${darkMode ? 'text-dark-primary' : 'text-light-primary'} d-flex align-items-center`}
            >
              <BiCart size="2rem" />
              {!isEmpty && <span style={{ position: 'relative', left: '-21px', top: '-18px' }}>{totalItems}</span>}
              <span style={{ marginLeft: !isEmpty ? '-13px' : 0 }}>&nbsp;Cart</span>
            </Link>
            <Link
              to="/wishlist"
              className={`${darkMode ? 'text-dark-primary' : 'text-light-primary'} d-flex align-items-center`}
            >
              <BiCart size="2rem" />
              {!isEmpty && <span style={{ position: 'relative', left: '-21px', top: '-18px' }}>{count.length}</span>}
              <span style={{ marginLeft: !isEmpty ? '-13px' : 0 }}>&nbsp;Wishlist</span>
            </Link>
            {
              isAuthenticated ? (
                <>

                  <button onClick={() => logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: window.location.origin } })} className={`login-btn ${darkMode ? 'text-dark-primary' : 'text-light-primary'}`}>
                    Log Out
                  </button>
                </>
              ) : (
                <>

                  <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()} className={`login-btn ${darkMode ? 'text-dark-primary' : 'text-light-primary'}`}>
                    Log in
                  </button>
                </>
              )
            }
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

ProductCard page:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useThemeHook } from '../GlobalComponents/ThemeProvider';
import { useCart } from 'react-use-cart';
import { BsCartPlus } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { Link } from "@reach/router";
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';

const ProductCard = (props) => {
    // const [state,setState]=useState({
    //     favourites:[]       
    //    });
    const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState([]);

    let { image, price, title, id } = props.data;
    const [theme] = useThemeHook();
    const { addItem } = useCart();

    const { ref: headerAni, inView: headerAniVisible } = useInView();

    const addToCart = () => {
        addItem(props.data);
    }
    const handleFavourites = (likedItem) => {
        let oldData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('liked')) ?? []
        if (favourites.includes(likedItem.id)) {
            oldData = oldData.filter((m) => m.id !== likedItem.id)
            console.log("if", oldData)

        } else {
            oldData.push(likedItem)
            console.log("else", oldData)
        }
        localStorage.setItem("liked", JSON.stringify(oldData));
        console.log(oldData);
        handleFavouritesState();
    };
    const handleFavouritesState = () => {
        let oldData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("liked")) ?? []
        let temp = oldData.map((likedItem) => likedItem.id);
        setFavourites([...temp])
        console.log("son", oldData)
    };

    return (
        <>

            <Card
                style={{ width: '18rem', height: 'auto' }}
                className={`${theme ? 'bg-light-black text-light' : 'bg-lihgt text-black'} text-center p-0 overflow-hidden shadow mx-auto mb-4`}

                ref={headerAni}
            >
                <Link to={`/product-details/${id}`}>
                    <div style={{
                        background: 'white', height: '15rem', overflow: 'hidden', display: 'flex',
                        justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 'inherit'
                    }}>
                        <div style={{ width: '9rem' }}>
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src={image} className="img-fluid" data-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic"
                                data-aos-duration="3000" data-aos={`${headerAniVisible ? "" : "zoom-out"}`} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Link>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title style={{ textOverflow: 'ellipsis', overflow: 'hidden', whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}>
                        {title}
                    </Card.Title>
                    <Card.Title>
                        $ <del><span className="">{price * 2}</span></del>
                    </Card.Title>
                    <Card.Title>
                        $ <span className="h3">{price}</span>
                    </Card.Title>
                    <Button
                        onClick={() => addToCart()}
                        className={`${theme ? 'bg-dark-primary text-black' : 'bg-light-primary'} d-flex align-item-center m-auto border-0`}
                    >
                        <BsCartPlus size="1.8rem" />
                        Add to cart
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        onClick={() => handleFavourites(props.data)}
                        className={`${theme ? 'bg-dark-primary text-black' : 'bg-light-primary'} d-flex align-item-center m-auto border-0`}
                    >
                        <BsCartPlus size="1.8rem" />
                        Add to Favourites
                    </Button>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </>
    );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

Comment: what does ```useEffect``` do in this code ? remove it.

Comment: What are you doing when you add item to the wishlist? The reason for warning probably because you are having infinite loop. You are listening count change and updating the same. Also if and else condition looks same. What is the difference?

Comment: just rendering page when i add or delete item from localStorage(when changes [count], am i wrong here? (it shows length of items in localStorage)

Comment: @CodeThing i am getting data from api, for showing items on homepage. and i added button (add to wishlist) and when i add item to wishlist i am adding item to localStorage. i need to show how many items i added to wishlist. Now i am adding to wishlist (localStorage) but i cant show count how many items i added. when i add it not shows. when i am reloading page i can see how many items i added

Comment: In that case you should add item to your __count__ state instead. So this will correctly render updated count. and useEffect will just listen to it and update your localstorage acccordingly.

Comment: @CodeThing not rendering and shows count when i change (add or delete) localStorage

Comment: @CodeThing i have useState on homepage (from where im adding items to localStorage) it adds items to localStorage.

Comment: @IlkinKarimov Added answer. Please check

Comment: @CodeThing Sir i am already adding items to my local storage from homepage and (how many items i added it must be show on header). i need to do something in header component. so when i delete item from wishlist page it must be -1 every time (when i delete from wishlist page)

Comment: @CodeThing so it just need to show me count when i add or delete items from localStorage. (from "liked") it shows only when i reload page

Comment: @IlkinKarimov You need to update your state if you need to your app to show your changes. updating localstorage alone cannot re-render the component. For deleting as well, as i mentioned in my answer below you just need to filter out removed items from state.

Comment: @CodeThing i added header and productCard check please

Comment: You cannot listen to changes on localstorage. you would either need to lift the state up (have wishlist state in some common component above the those components) or better use Context

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot bro. i just used Context and everything goo now! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments. You are getting warning because you are having infinite loop as you are listening to and updating the same state.

Here is what you can try. When you click Add to wishlist just update your count state. Append new item to your existing wishlist stored in the count state. And then the useEffect will take care of adding/synching wishlist to the localstorage.

```
export default function App() {
  // Initial state will pull wishlist items from localstorage and set it in state
  const [count, setCount] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("liked")) || []);

  // This is your add to wishlist function. You can create similar function to remove item from wishlist. In that case you just need to filter the count state.
  const addToWishlist = (item) => {
    setCount(prev => [...prev, item]);
  };

  // This will update your localstorage whenever state changes.
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("liked", JSON.stringify(count));
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Wishlist</h1>
      <h2>{count.length}</h2>
      <button onClick={() => addToWishlist({id: 1, name: 'test'})}>Add to Wishlist</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```